# OpenVPN per user rules while not routing Internet traffic

Tags: iptables, routing, openvpn, access-control-list

***EDIT***: I know that `learn-address` is what I would need to use to call a script (as specified in the `openvpn-netfilter` project) to set the firewall rules. I guess my question is more related to the `config.ovpn` script. How do you configure the `client.ovpn` files to simultaneously learn which routes to the user needs, while also keeping Internet traffic to the user's ISP?

I have a question about how to do per user firewall rules, while also **not** routing Internet traffic through an OpenVPN server. I'm trying to setup a VPN server for a group of friends and I as we work on a project. I will implement something like this Github project: https://github.com/gdestuynder/openvpn-netfilter. This will enable the VPN server to lookup ACLs for a user, and implement them using `iptables` on the server side. All other traffic would be dropped.

For my own personal home VPN, I know I can use the following in my `client.ovpn` config to **not** route Internet traffic through the VPN:

```
route-nopull
route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
```

Where `192.168.1.0/24` is my home subnet, and `10.8.0.0/24` (not shown) is the DHCP IP range of the `tun` adapter. I know placing that in the client's configuration overrides the server setting `push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"`.

This is where I get confused: I already know my home subnet is `192.168.1.0/24`, so I can easily place that in the `client.ovpn` file. But if I have no knowledge of the subnets/IPs I have access to (as most users don't), how does OpenVPN dynamically push per user VPN rules to the client?

In other words, if `user1` has acess to `10.0.0.2` and `10.0.2.10` and `user2` has access to `10.0.2.10` and `10.0.3.4`, how does OpenVPN know to push the right routes to each user, while using the same generic `client.ovpn` configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can push individual openvpn directives to your clients using client specific configuration files in the client-config-dir.

In the server config file include the directive:

```
client-config-dir ccd
```

and create this directory in case it does not already exist in your openvpn path, for example:

```
/etc/openvpn/ccd
```

Now create a config file per client in the `ccd` directory having the same name as the client's X509 common name. The following options are legal in a client-specific context: `push`, `push-reset`, `iroute`, `ifconfig-push`, and `config`.

For example to push routes to a client with CN `user1` in his certificate:

```
echo 'push "route 10.0.0.2 255.255.255.255 10.8.0.1"' >> /etc/openvpn/ccd/user1
echo 'push "route 10.0.2.10 255.255.255.255 10.8.0.1"' >> /etc/openvpn/ccd/user1
```

For this to work you need to pull configuration directives on your clients from the server using the `pull` directive.

You may have the directive `client` in your client-config, which is a helper directive and expands as follows:

```
pull
tls-client
```

Do not use `route-nopull` in combination as it would stop the client pulling routes. If you need `redirect-gateway` on certain clients to route all traffic through the VPN subnet, you can place this directive just in those client configuration files and not in your server config file for all clients. The `redirect-gateway` directive automatically executes routing commands to cause all outgoing IP traffic to be redirected over the VPN. See [man](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn23ManPage) page.

Comment: Does this apply if I'm using a script in `learn-address` to pull configuration information from LDAP?

Comment: Yes, the `client-config-dir` configuration is parsed after a connecting client has been authenticated, the `learn-address` script is run whenever a client virtual address or route is learned or unlearned.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone wanting to know an alternative answer, the following should also be useful. When you use the `client-connect` script, OpenVPN passes one argument to your script: the path to a temporary file that where you can add `push "route 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0"` like statements. This serves as a dynamic CCD-like file without the need for generating static CCD files.